# Nullable DateTime vs. relying on default( DateTIme )

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, ef-code-first, nullable

My C# class has a date/time property that I will use Code First to map to a column in an SQL Server database.  This date will never be prior or close to default( DateTime ).  If I type the property as `System.DateTime` then I could always check for an unset value with `MyProp == default( DateTime )`.

Is there a compelling reason whether or not to type this property as a (nullable) `DateTime?` instead of a (non-nullable) `DateTime`?  Why?

Comment: Sometimes, you don't have the option of using a Nullable. For example, it could be an issue with Serialization; I tend to convert all `DateTime?` instances to `DateTime`  (null => MinValue) and convert from back to null on deserializing...

Comment: Storing the ***wrong*** value that means something completely different *by convention* is a maintenance hazard that might be manageable now, but could bite you in 6 months time (or a stranger who has to maintain your code). On the other hand, `null` is unambiguous.

Comment: The reason I see is if you business rules enforce 3 different cases: a DateTime value provided by a user, a default date time that represents some special case and an unintialized date time value represented by a null DateTime value. Similar to a TriState check box.

Answer (score 1):

A sentinel value for some type like an integer in my opinion make sense when it relates to a record ID. It makes less sense when zero is a legitimate at value (as in the value could also be negative). Dates always have meaning so null is more informative as a "we don't when" value. Also I think it makes a "give me all records where we don't have a date" query look much cleaner.

Comment: Although the `default( DateTime )` value is legitimate in a general sense, in more specific cases (like mine) it's too early to be valid. That and making a query appear cleaner are good but not compelling reasons by themselves. I'm wondering if there are additional reasons and/or something more practical that comes into play, like performance